# Angular 2 Typescript equivalent of $cookies.token

Tags: cookies, angular, typescript

I have some Angular 1 Javascript code I am trying to rewrite in Angular 2 Typescript.

I am stuck on how to write the Angular 2 Typescript version of:

```
$cookies.token
```

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem('token-key', token-value);
localStorage.getItem('token-key');
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: I am looking to pick up cookies sent via an http request, not cookies made by me.